# Why Lazy<T> forces initialization during serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-evaluation

When I checked the implementation of Lazy`<T>` class, I saw this block:

```
[OnSerializing]
private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)  
{  
     T obj = this.Value;  
}
```

As you can see it's forcing initialization during serialization. Does anyone know why this behavior is preferred as default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it doesnt and you provided lambda for initialization, where do you think it retrives the value on deserializing? lambdas are not serializable.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but you are wrong about lambdas not being serializable. Some lambda expressions can be serialized, however it is not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a `Lazy<T>` is to delay evaluation until it's needed. This can save you processing power by not calculating things until you actually need to. When you serialise something, you generally want to serialise its value, so `Lazy<T>` has to work out what that value *is* so that you can serialise it.

Comment: it doesnt answer his question because you dont neccessarly need its value when serializing. it is because you cant serialize lambdas and delay the evaluation.

Comment: It depends on what T is, but yeah, that's *why* you need the value. You can't rely on being able to serialise the evaluation function, so you serialise its result.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if anyone has a workaround.  We use Lazy on many of our objects and it works great except when we put our objects into our custom ASP.NET cache because all the Lazy typed properties of our objects are serialized into the cache with the .Value evaluated.  This means that there is the expensive "eager" loading of these lazy delegate functions.  Most of them are expensive database/repository layer

Comment: a) This isn't an answer. b) Perhaps add an attribute to the property so it won't get serialised / deserialised?